# Understanding the Derivation of Dual Geometric Programming Problem

Tags: optimization, functional-inequalities

Enthusiastic CS major interested in Optimization Theory here. Pardon me for overlooking something obvious.

I'm referring to this nice tutorial/ebook: http://faculty.uml.edu/cbyrne/optfirst0.pdf

In this, I'm specifically looking at Chapter 3, Section 3.3 (pages 26, 27). I understand the part till where the author applies GAGM (Generalized Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality) to the posynomial. However, I did not understand the reduction from step (3.6) to (3.7). Can anyone help explaining this?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement $(3\cdot 7)$ says:
$$g(t)\geq \prod_{j=1}^m\left(\frac{u_j(t)}{\delta_j}\right)^{\delta_j}\tag{3.6}$$

And we know that from $(3\cdot 3)$ in the book:
$$u_j(t)=c_i\prod_{i=1}^{n}t_i^{a_i,j} \tag{3.3}$$

if we replace $(3.3)$ in $(3.6)$ we obtain:
$$g(t)\geq \prod_{j=1}^m\left(\frac{u_j(t)}{\delta_j}\right)^{\delta_j}= \prod_{j=1}^m\left(\frac{c_i\prod_{i=1}^{n}t_i^{a_i,j} }{\delta_j}\right)^{\delta_j}=\prod_{j=1}^m\left(\frac{c_j}{\delta_j}\right)^{\delta_j}\left(\prod_{j=1}^m\prod_{i=1}^nt_i^{a_{i,j}\delta_j}\right)$$

which gives you $(3.7)$

Comment: Ohh! I see...So the first term with the (cj/dj) is _separately_ multiplied with the rest of the stuff. I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: As a side question, after statement (3.4), would you know why the author thinks the condition of all d(j) for j=1,2,..,m to sum to 1 is necessary?

Comment: It's just a rewriting of the identity $3.2$ which is the definition of psynomials